# Cross-domain will not work with a SignalR PersistentConnection

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, signalr, signalr.client

**NOTE**: Someone else originally asked this question but deleted it before I could post my answer. Since this question covers many issues that developers face when trying to make SignalR work cross-domain, I decided to replicate it. Plus, I had already finished writing the answer!

I'm running a SignalR 1.0.1 server in an ASP.NET MVC .NET Framework 4 project. I have another ASP.NET application on a different domain (different localhost port) trying to connect via the JavaScript client. I get this when my application tries to connect:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:31865/api/negotiate?_=1363105027533.
Origin http://localhost:64296 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've followed all steps to enable cross-domain support with SignalR -- what am I missing?

- `jQuery.support.cors = true;`
- `$.connection('http://localhost:31865/api', '', false, { jsonp: true, xdomain: true });`
- `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });`
- `RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<ApiConnection>("/api", "api");`

I also added the following to Web.config in the API project:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm using a PersistentConnection for my SignalR server, not hubs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @halter73, can you provide me a demo for multiple chat rooms using signalR. I want to implement chat server like chat.stackoverflow.com OR any link. Please help me. i have a demo but not working. can email you my demo?

Comment: my email id is: moaman@88gmail.com. if u have any demo please send me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MapHubs` will configure an endpoint at /signalr for communicating with all your `Hub` classes. Since you are not using Hubs, the call to `MapHubs` is unnecessary. The call to `MapHubs` also does not have any effect on the configuration of your /api connection.

Your call to MapConnection should be changed to read as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<ApiConnection>("api", "api",
    new ConnectionConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

**NOTE:** The second argument to `MapConnection` is the URL. The first argument is the route name. The `/` is unnecessary, but doesn't really hurt in either case.

- Setting `jQuery.support.cors = true;` should **ONLY** be done "To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc)" [`[1]`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/). This does not pertain to any versions of IE or any other browser that I know of. If the browser does not support CORS, SignalR will already automatically fall back to JSONP **unless** you set `jQuery.support.cors` to true.

  If you just set this to true blindly, SignalR will assume that the environment does support cross-domain XHR requests and **not** automatically fall back to JSONP rendering SignalR unable to establish cross-domain connections while running in browsers that truly don't support CORS.
- `$.connection('http://localhost:31865/api', '', false, { jsonp: true, xdomain: true });` is incorrect. You should only need

  ```
  var connection = $.connection('http://localhost:31865/api');
  ```

  `xdomain` is no longer an option for the SignalR JS client, and if you *really* want to specify `jsonp`, you should do it when you `start` the connection like so:

  ```
   connection.start({ jsonp: true}).done(function () { /* ... */ });
  ```

  I should reiterate that SignalR will *automatically* fall back to JSONP if the environment does not support CORS, so you **should not** specify this option yourself. JSONP does not require an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but it does force SignalR to use its most inefficient transport: long polling.
- You do not need to setup `customHeaders` in your Web.config. SignalR will set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in SignalR responses automatically when you set `EnableCrossDomain` to true in you `ConnectionConfiguration`.

Reference https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections for more advice abut using `PersistentConnections`.