# IE 10, singalr error, error during negotiation request: undefined

Tags: signalr, internet-explorer-10, signalr.client

I have a singalr self hosted server which has enable cross domain, enable javascript proxies and I have a javascript no proxy client with jquery.support.cors =true. **My client is hosted in SSL and my server is not.** My javascript clients works fine in latest chrome and mozilla except IE 10.

Yes I do have ramfar enabled, I also have access-control-allow-origin set in my webconfig file I am not sure what is going on

IE just gives me SignalR: Error during negotiation request: undefined 
Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
If this helps, when shutting down Https on my client it works in IE 10 too, so some how SSL on IE 10 does not allow singalr to connect via proxy..

Thanks.

Comment: Ok I aswered my own question here
Here is a way i made my self-host singalR server to be in SSL
and that removed the error i was getting from IE 10 http://bhavinsurela.com/setup-singalr-self-host-in-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SignalR from an SSL website, the SignalR endpoint must also be SSL if you want IE 10 to work yet this is still best practice in general.

Additionally, to enable cross-domain support in SignalR, all you need to do is:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

Enabling RAMFAR and changing the webconfig is unnecessary. Setting `jquery.support.cors` to true is [counterproductive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367968/cross-domain-will-not-work-with-a-signalr-persistentconnection).

Comment: ok so how do i make a self hosted singalR server to use SSL. I am self hosting my singalR package via Owin package from nuget.