# Weird behavior of CORS with signalR and ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr, cors

I'm using signalR 0.5.3, my web application is located at `localhost:1234`, my hub is at `localhost:5678`, which means same host name and different ports. Both are on IIS 7 Express, Windows 7.

When I add this to `web.config` of my hub server.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

The Google Chrome's console yells:

```
 The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'http://localhost:1234, *'.
```

But when I remove that config, it yells:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I searched all over the solution to make sure that there was nowhere to have

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

or

```
map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Does anyone know why hub server keeps returning 2 orgins and how to tell it to do the right job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable cross-domain SignalR requests with SignalR 0.5.3, you should call `MapHubs` as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

Manually manipulating the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is likely to cause problems since SignalR will set the header for you if you enable cross-domain access in `MapHubs`.

`IAppBuilder.UseCors` is OWIN middleware provided by the [Microsoft.Owin.Cors](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/) NuGet package. This middleware is not compatible with SignalR 0.5.3, but can be used with newer versions of SignalR which don't have the EnableCrossDomain option.

I go over some other common SignalR cross-domain pitfalls in the following answer: [Cross-domain will not work with a SignalR PersistentConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367968/cross-domain-will-not-work-with-a-signalr-persistentconnection)